# Updating nested entities with constraints without getting spaghettimadness

Tags: asp.net, clean-code, entity-framework, trees

I have an endpoint "import" that is supposed to accept an entity. This entity can contain several sub-entities with yet again some sub-entities. Since this is an "import" endpoint, some of the entites or sub-entities may exist from previous imports some may not, some are required and some are not. Some have special rules (ex email cannot be duplicate of other entity's email) and so forth.

Is there a technique, pattern, or algorithm that makes this code simpler to write cleanly? Everytime there is a bug in this logic we have to add another or several "if's" and it is getting quite out of hand.

I'm thinking; this is basicly a tree with rules in some of the nodes and leafs. There might be something clever out there that we dont know of.

Might not be important but this is an ASP.Net Web API with Enity Framework serving as the ORM towards a SQL relational database

**Update 1**

[image: This is a rough outline of what I'm dealing with structurally]

This is a rough outline of what I'm dealing with structurally.

The import recieves a list of users with all sub-entities attached.

```
{
  users:[
    {
      prop1: value1,
      prop2: value2,
      company 
      {
        prop1: value1
      },
      ...,
    },{..}
  ]
}
```

All of the entities in this structure has several valuetype properties.
With the import function needing to handle all cases of the incoming entities either existing in the db or not, and connect them to the correct entity via the FK releationship.

What I'm seeing now is perhaps that this is not a tree at all, more a graph or directed graph?

I dont know if this extra bit helps, but I think it fleshes out the problem a bit more. Keep in mind that I'm not really looking for an actual solution to this problem. What bothers me the most is that this must be a problem that a lot of developers comes across in one form or another. I'm curious to know if there is any smart ways to tackle this?

Comment: Can any of these sub-entities derive from the same interface?

Comment: If too many if's are your problem there are ways to refactor them to [strategies](https://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionalWithStrategy.html) or [commands](https://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionDispatcherWithCommand.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution if you don't mind just exposing the raw exceptions.

I assume you are enforcing the restrictions in the Database?

Simply attempt to save the item and mark it errored if the save fails with whatever exception message was thrown. Obviously its best to import things into temporary 'Import Tables' to allow for a publish process for 'I only want to import the items if the *all* work'

Normally, I would apply the validation logic in the Repository, which allows for slightly nicer error messages and handling. This encapsulated the validation logic, but doesn't really help with its complexity

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Web API, have you considered something similar to DataAnnotations [validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx) attributes? This would let you set validation rules on properties or classes and then any validation errors would then get collected as part of your ASP.NET ModelState. If you pair this with an [ActionFilter and ResultFilter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) in the request pipeline that starts and commits/rollbacks a transaction on the way in and out of the "import" endpoint, you can also add the DB validation in each of these attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a better way to do this. Its been staring me in the face all along. I was incorrectly assuming that everything must be imported as one giant structure. But this is not necessarily true.

By adding an import endpoint that takes Companies and its sub entities (email, phonenumber, department) the whole problem is more or less split in two smaller more maintainable pieces.

The problem that really drove me to write this post was that Companies needed to be imported differently. This change really messed up the flow which was already quite difficult to really understand.

By making a separate import endpoint for companies I can keep the old one for users, maybe clean it up a bit. The import endpoint is currently only used for tools that we control, so the api-change is not an issue.

Thanks for the responses guys.